# Sequential return of a string of numbers

Tags: python, sequencing

In python, if I have a text list with names and scores I want a string of code that will reorder this list sequentially based on entry of a new or repeated name and score.

Comment: Btw, I may not be asking the question in a way that programmers would understand as I'm a complete novice on python. Any help VERY much appreciated iated

Comment: Hello! Please, add some example code of your text list and an example of your expected result after adding a new or repeated name and score. And what you have tried so far too: don't expect that people write code for you.